# Does the QtWebKit module within Qt support ActiveX controls?

Tags: qt, activex, qtwebkit

I'm attempting to use QtWebKit (specifically, a QWebView widget) to display a web page that contains an ActiveX control.  On my first attempt, the ActiveX control doesn't appear to be loading.  I'm wondering if QtWebKit actually supports ActiveX controls, and I can't immediately find any documentation that gives an answer one way or another.

Does QtWebKit/QWebView support ActiveX controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK The only rendering engine with native support for ActiveX controls is MSIE.  However, there is a QT component that will wrap an ActiveX control (called [QAxWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qaxwidget.html) IIRC) and a QT [browser plugin framework](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Utilities/qtbrowserplugin) that emulates a netscape plugin.  You might be able to use these to embed an ActiveX control within the QT container and display this through Webkit (which [supports the netscape plugin API](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/webintegration.html#netscape-plugin-support)).

That's a fairly convoluted approach, but making a component with the browser plugin framework [is fairly straightforward](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/solutions/4/qtbrowserplugin/qtbrowserplugin-example-trivial.html) and displaying it on a page is simple.  The ActiveX wrapper component could probably be fairly easily built into a plugin of this type, so implementing it might not be all that complex.

Answer (score 1):

While WebKit can be used as an ActiveX control, it does not support ActiveX controls within it.

Answer (score 0):

While WebKit doesn't host ActiveX controls, you can use an NPAPI plugin to wrap an ActiveX plugin. If you can live with it's license (LGPL), [ff-activex-host](http://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/) already provides this functionality.